# Custom token endpoint with JHipster UAA service

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, jhipster

I am building a microservice + UAA JHipster application and am trying to provide a login endpoint in addition to the already existing `/auth/login` endpoint. The purpose is to be able to send a link with a token in the URL to a user, which gives him/her access to my services without having to register or sign in (similar to share with link in google drive). The user should then receive a JWT token with the "GUEST" role.

In my gateway I created a second endpoint `/auth/login-guest` but I am stuck when the gateway performs the call to the uaa service. The original login method posts to `http://uaa/oauth/token` but I can't find, where in the UAA service this endpoint is actually implemented. Is there an easy way to add a `http://uaa/auth/guest-token` endpoint in the UAA service?